# Google News scraper to fetch links with similar stories

Tags: python, web-scraping

The following code takes either a URL or the title to an existing news article.

1. Searches Google News using the title.
2. Collects all links from search results.

```
import urllib2
from lxml import html
import requests

def get_page_tree(url=None):
    page = requests.get(url=url, verify=False)
    return html.fromstring(page.text)

def get_title(url=None):
    tree = get_page_tree(url=url)
    return tree.xpath('//title//text()')[0].strip().split(' -')[0]

def find_other_news_sources(url=None, title=None):
    # Google forwards the url using <google_domain>/url?q=    <actual_link>. This might change over time
    forwarding_identifier = '/url?q='
    if not title:
        title = get_title(url=url)
    google_news_search_url = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=' + urllib2.quote(title) + '&tbm=nws'
    google_news_search_tree = get_page_tree(url=google_news_search_url)
    other_news_sources_links = [a_link.replace(forwarding_identifier, '').split('&')[0] for a_link in
                            google_news_search_tree.xpath('//a//@href') if forwarding_identifier in a_link]
    return other_news_sources_links
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why do all of your function arguments have default values of `None`? What purpose would these functions serve if they were run with all argument values as `None`?

Secondly, you should have two blank lines between your functions, as per [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Finally, I'd recommend adding [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) to your functions, and your file as well. A typical function docstring looks something like this:

```
def my_func( ... ):
    """
    Put a description of your function
    and it's arguments here.
    """
    ...
```

Anyways, other than that, your code looks really nice! Keep up the good work!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I agree with the None part. Unneccesary. Looking into PEP8 and docstring now.

Answer (score 3):

1. Instead of constructing the `google_news_search_url` with two string concatenations, use [string formatting](http://pyformat.info/).
2. The `other_news_sources_links` line is very dense. Please split it up.
3. In addition to the defaults for all your args being `None`, you're calling all of your functions with keyword arguments, which seems unnecessary.
4. But before you fix that, consider why you need these 2 line functions in the first place. They don't seem to do anything complicated enough to warrant having to jump around in the code.